# Knockout binding works in text attribute but throws undefined error when used in href

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

I have the following binding within a **[`foreach`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)** binding:

```
<h5>Id: <span data-bind="text: ($root.link + id)"/></h5>
```

and it displays fine.
If I change it out for

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: $root.link}"/>
```

the anchor navigates fine (except obviously the `id` isn't appended to the end).
If I add in the `id`

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: $root.link +id}"/>
```

I get 'Unable to parse binding ... id is undefined'.

Why does the exact same binding syntax work with text but not the attr binding?

Thanks for your help.

Update:  I am using [Breezejs](http://www.breezejs.com/) which uses the metadata to create the **[`observableArray`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)**.  I've have done more testing and discovered that the binding fails when the field is of type `integer`.  I passed in the name field and the binding works fine.  I also tried `Id.toString()` but still get the Id undefined error.  As suggested below, I am considering using a computed to solve the problem. If this is the only solution, I think it would be better to extend the breeze entity so it flows through to any downstream view model.

Comment: I don't know specifically why you're running into this problem, but I do know that the `a` tag needs to have a closing tag: `<a></a>` when used as a link.

Comment: Just so you know I have had issues with knockout have a span tag like this <span data-bind="text: ($root.link + id)"/> where there is no explicit closing tag. I do not know if this is knockout or an html issue since a <span /> tag is not valid because you are supposed to have it like <span>Something</span> Just an FYI

Answer (score 0):

You need a computed observable called linkUrl.

self.linkUrl = ko.computed(function(){
    return $root.link + id;
});

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html

Comment: How would that help? `link` and `id` don't appear to be observable?

Comment: They dont have to be, they just have to be in his model which they obviously are since they are in the foreach.